# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity

Tags: android, google-maps

In my android application I've given event option on overflow menu and on the event option the map is loaded but when I'm pressing back button the application unfortunately stopped. I've posted the code nad logcat as well.

```
AlertActivity.java

    public class Alert_activity extends Activity implements
    OnItemSelectedListener{
    Spinner s1,s2;
    TextView t1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_activity);
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
          //  Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(sp1.contentEquals("Events")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Heavy Rain(mm/hr)");
                list.add("Smoke/Fog");
                list.add("Heat/Cold Wave");
                list.add("Strong Winds");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                            int position, long id) {


                        // On selecting a spinner item
                        String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Log.d("Inside loop","inside loop");

                        // Showing selected spinner item
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            //  "You have selected : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("Item",item);
                         FragmentTransaction tx = getFragmentManager()
                                    .beginTransaction();


                         if(item=="Heavy Rain(mm/hr)")
                        {
                            tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new heavyrain());
                            /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    MainActivity1.class);

                                startActivityForResult(in, 100);*/
                        }
                         else if(item=="Smoke/Fog")
                         {
                             tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new smoke_fog());
                         }
                         else if(item=="Heat/Cold Wave")
                         {
                             tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new smoke_fog());
                         }
                         else if(item=="Strong Winds")
                         {
                             tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new smoke_fog());
                         }
                        tx.commit();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

            }
            if(sp1.contentEquals("Forecast")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                list.add("Cyclone");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
                s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // On selecting a spinner item
                        String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Log.d("Inside loop","inside loop");

                        // Showing selected spinner item
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            //  "You have selected : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("Item",item);
                         FragmentTransaction tx = getFragmentManager()
                                    .beginTransaction();

                        if(item=="Cyclone")
                        {
                            tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new Cyclone());
                            /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                MapActivity.class);

                            startActivityForResult(in, 100);*/

                        }
                /*      else if(item=="Heavy Rain")
                        {
                            tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new forecast_heavyrain());

                        }
                        else if(item=="Cloudburst")
                        {
                            tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new forecast_cloudburst());

                        }*/
                        tx.commit();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            }

            if(sp1.contentEquals("Nowcast")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Heavy Rain");

                list.add("Cloudburst");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
                s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // On selecting a spinner item
                        String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Log.d("Inside loop","inside loop");

                        // Showing selected spinner item
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            //  "You have selected : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("Item",item);
                         FragmentTransaction tx = getFragmentManager()
                                    .beginTransaction();

                         if(item=="Heavy Rain")
                        {
                            tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new forecast_heavyrain());
                            /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    MainActivity1.class);

                                startActivityForResult(in, 100);*/
                        }
                        else if(item=="Cloudburst")
                        {
                            tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new forecast_cloudburst());
                            /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    MainActivity1.class);

                                startActivityForResult(in, 100);*/
                        }
                        tx.commit();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });

            }


private GoogleMap googleMap;
    PolylineOptions polylineOptions=new PolylineOptions(); 
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    String lat12[] = {"30.5","31.0","31.2","31.8","30.65"};
    String long12[] = {"79.9","78.1","78.0","78.8","78.8"};
    String time11[]={"6AUG2014 20:45GMT","6AUG2014 20:45GMT","6AUG2014 20:45GMT","6AUG2014 20:45GMT","6AUG2014 22:45GMT"};
    TextView rain;
    TextView rain_lat;
    TextView rain_long;

    String[] time=new String[100];
    String[] date=new String[100];
    String[] rain_lat1=new String[100];
    String[] rain_long1=new String[100];
    String[] rad_inf1=new String[100];
    ArrayList high_rain = new ArrayList();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View root = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.forecast_heavyrain, container,false);
         initilizeMap();
         return root;
    }
        private void initilizeMap()
        {
            arrayPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.fragment4);
            googleMap = fm.getMap();
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
            googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this); 
            googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);


            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LAT", "LAT"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LONGITUDE", "LONG"));
            Log.d("params", params.toString());
            // getting weather details by making HTTP request
            // Note that weather details url will use GET request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Weather_details1,
                    "GET", params);
            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Weather Details", json.toString());
            // json success tag
            int success = 0;
            try {
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully received weather details
                JSONArray stationObj = null;
                try {
                    stationObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_WEATHER);

                    // JSON Array

                    int lengthJsonArr = stationObj.length();
                    Log.d("length",String.valueOf(lengthJsonArr));

                    for (int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) 
                    //for (int i = 0; i < lat12.length; i++) 
                    {
                        station = stationObj.getJSONObject(i);
                        /*String time1=station.getString(TAG_time);
                        time[i]=time1;*/

                        String lat1=station.getString(TAG_rain_lat);
                        rain_lat1[i]=lat1;

                        String long1=station.getString(TAG_rain_long);
                        rain_long1[i]=long1;

                        String date_nowcast=station.getString(TAG_date);
                        date[i]=date_nowcast;

                        String time_nowcast=station.getString(TAG_time);
                        time[i]=time_nowcast;

                        String rad_inf=station.getString(TAG_rad_inf);
                        rad_inf1[i]=rad_inf;

                    }
                //  Log.d("Length",String.valueOf(time.length));
                    int i;
                    for ( i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) 
                    {
                        //for(i=0; i<time11.length;i++)
                        //{
                        //Log.d("high rain size",String.valueOf(highest_rain.length));
                        //double high_rain2=Double.parseDouble(time[i]);


                        double lat2=Double.parseDouble(rain_lat1[i]);
                        Log.d("Latitude===>",String.valueOf(lat2));

                        double long2=Double.parseDouble(rain_long1[i]);
                        Log.d("Longitude===>",String.valueOf(long2));

                        Log.d("time_nowcast==>",time[i]);

                        Log.d("Date_nowcast==>",date[i]);
                        Log.d("Radius of influence==>",rad_inf1[i]);

                        /*t1=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.rain11);
                        t1.setText(String.valueOf(high_rain2));*/

                    //    double lat2=Double.parseDouble(lat12[i]);
                    //  Log.d("Latitude===>",String.valueOf(lat2));
                    /// double long2=Double.parseDouble(long12[i]);
                    //  Log.d("Longitude===>",String.valueOf(long2));
                        //double high_rain2=Double.parseDouble(time11[i]);
                    //  Log.d("time===>",String.valueOf(time11[i])); 

                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat2, long2);
                         CameraPosition cameraPosition;// = new CameraPosition(latLng, 0, 0, 0);
                         cameraPosition = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(position, (float) 14.0);


                        Marker marker =  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat2, long2)) .title(" Forecast Date: "+date[i]+" Forecast Time:"+ time[i]).snippet(" Radius of Influence:"+rad_inf1[i]+" kms").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.heavy_rain11)));

                        points.add(position);
                    //  Log.d("i inside for loop",String.valueOf(i));


                        }



                /*  polylineOptions.addAll(points);
                    polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                    polylineOptions.width(7); 
                    polylineOptions.width(7); 
                    googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);*/

        }

                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(success==2)
            {
                Log.d("success 2","success 2");



            }
            else if(success==3)
            {
                Log.d("success 3","success 3");

            }   
}
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void onDestroyView() 
         {
                 super.onDestroyView(); 
                 Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment4));  
                 FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 ft.remove(fragment);
                 ft.commit();
                 super.onDestroy();
         }
        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();

            try {
                Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
                childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
                childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.exit:
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);

            case R.id.Feedback:
                LocationFound();
                return true;

            case R.id.Events:
                Alert();
                return true;


            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();



        }

        return true;
    }
    private void LocationFound() {
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Feedback.class);
        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
    }
    private void Alert() {
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Alert_activity.class);
        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { //here I capture the event onBackPress 
        super.onBackPressed(); 
        onStop(); //call onStop
    }

}
```

logcat

```
    02-01 08:27:22.651: E/AndroidRuntime(12401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-01 08:27:22.651: E/AndroidRuntime(12401): Process: com.example.gpstracking, PID: 12401
    02-01 08:27:22.651: E/AndroidRuntime(12401): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.gpstracking/com.example.gpstracking.Alert_activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    02-01 08:27:22.651: E/AndroidRuntime(12401):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3515)
    02-01 08:27:22.651: E/AndroidRuntime(12401):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3533)
    02-01 08:27:22.651: E/AndroidRuntime(12401):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400
```

Comment: why you are calling `onStop();` in `onBackPressed`?

Comment: If i m removing this..then also the problem remains same...

Comment: Yes if i m removing this then also the error remains same...i think the problem is with the fragment...but i can't solve it..

Comment: Try removing `onDestroyView` method. You can't use `getActivity()` when it is destroyed already.

Comment: i have to display maps in different fragment...so if m removing the destroy view then also the application gets stopped...actually this problem is arise in only android version 4.4 and higher...for other version it works fine...if you can help me in what i m suppose to write in my code,it would be a great help for me...thank you so much...

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code in onBackPressed() method instead of calling onStop():

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Hope this would Help!!